# facebook: how to get group feeds?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get feeds from a facebook group, I used the facebook graph API (PHP sdk), here is an example from the facebook docs:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{group-id}/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

what the `$session` should be? how I can declare it?

[facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group/feed)

Comment: Try this [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile); use the example code and replace user `me` with page id;

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to make request throw graph API

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

// Since all the requests will be sent on behalf of the same user,
// we'll set the default fallback access token here.
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('user-access-token');

$requestUserName = $fb->request('GET', '/{group-id}/feed');
```